# Combine 2 MongoDB collections in Java

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I have 2 MongoDB collections, named "product" and "file_data", "file_data" contains images of a single product in "product" by productId.

Entity Product

```
public class Product {
    private String id;
    private String link;
    private String externalId;
    private String createdBy;
    private Date createdStamp;
}
```

Entity FileData

```
public class FileData {
    private String id;
    private Date date;
    private String createdBy;
    private String productId;
    private String fileName;
```

How can I retrieve product information as JSON like this:

```
"data": {
        "id": "3793",
        "link": "https://example.com/abc.jpg,
        "externalId": "562282907969",
        "createdBy": "123456@gmail.com",
        "createdStamp": 1624330935051,
        "images": {
                       "id": "zxc",
                       "date": "1624330935051",
                       "createdBy": "123456@gmail.com",
                       "productId": "3793",
                       "fileName": "abc.jpg",
                  },
                  {
                       "id": "zxc",
                       "date": "1624330935051",
                       "createdBy": "123456@gmail.com",
                       "productId": "3793",
                       "fileName": "abc.jpg",
                  },
}
```

Here is my code:

```
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getProducts() {
        try {
            HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
            JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
            List<Product> products = getProductManager().getProductsByPartyId(getAuth().getString("partyGroupId"));
            if (null != products && products.size() > 0) {
                products.forEach(product -> {
                    list.put(getFileDataManager().getFileDataList(product.getId(), "PRODUCT"));
                });
                result.put("data", products);
                result.put("status", 1);
            }
            return result(result);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return Response.status(400).entity(getErrorMessage(ex.getMessage())).build();
        }
    }
```

It only shows

```
"data": {
        "id": "3793",
        "link": "https://example.com/abc.jpg,
        "externalId": "562282907969",
        "createdBy": "123456@gmail.com",
        "createdStamp": 1624330935051,
}
```

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: You can "join" Products and FileData with the `productId` field. MongoDB has a [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation stage which is used for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is there a way to show JSON as I asked above using only Java code like the code above? Or is my code missing something?

Comment: You can write an aggregate query using $lookup using Java driver: [MongoDB Java - Aggregation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver/tutorials/aggregation/).